# Contar los registros de un solo mes

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un simple consulta para obtener los registro de un solo mes, en mi caso, el mes actual. Tengo una tabla que guarda la fecha en formato `17/12/2018 01:12` ya que el cliente lo pidio asi.

Lo que trato de hacer es esto:

```
<?php
$fecha = date('m');
$sql_cuenta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM prReserv WHERE fecha = '".$fecha."'");

echo "Cantidad de registros este mes: ".$sql_cuenta->rowCount();
?>
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es `0` cuando tendria que ser `8`, que son los 8 registro que hay guardados. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes darle formato al campo de la fecha, para que solamente tome el mes necesario; te dejo como debería ser tu consulta con un ejemplo

```
<?php
$fecha = date('m');
$sql_cuenta = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM prReserv WHERE MONTH(fecha) = '".$fecha."'");

?>
```

Lo que hice fue:

1. Asumiendo que la var `$fecha` vale solo el numérico de un mes, por ejemplo 12
2. Uso la función `MONTH()` para que de la columna que tiene tu tabla con el formato así: `17/12/2018 01:12` solo tome el valor de `12` entonces se proceda a hacer la comparación
3. Se supone que indicas querer obtener el conteo de registros por un mes específico, por lo que se hace necesario usar una función de agregación como `COUNT()` que ayuda a hacer el conteo de los valores de la tabla que ya previamente estan condicionados por el mes que sea igual al que tu le pasas

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Finalmente para poder mostrar los resultados puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cuenta);
echo $fila["Total"];
```

> En el código anterior como puedes ver para poder imprimir el total de
>   registros del mes en cuestión hice uso del alias `Total` que le
>   declare al uso de la función `COUNT`

Comment: oh podria usar la funcion count si solo necesita contar la cantida de   registro en una columna.

Comment: Gracias @shadow, y cambie el formato en la base de datos, estaba como `varchar` y no fomo `datetime`, pero ahora resulta que la fecha no se guarda, me queda todo en `0000-00-00 00:00:00:000000`

Comment: si cambiaste el formato de la columna que estaba de `varchar` a `datetime` ahora deberás rfespetar dicho formato para dar de alta, te sugiero revisar la posibilidad de cambiar el tipo de dato; siempre y cuando no afectes a la data que ahi esta

Comment: Claro, si.... me había olvidado del formato, ahora si... todo funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando tengas datos de varios años tendrás problemas, usa `DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y%m') = '$fecha_anio_mes' `  para comparar tambien el año.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar **Count** para contar los registros de meses en *MySQL* por ejemplo mira así:

Este es tu código:

> ```
> $sql_cuenta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM prReserv WHERE fecha = '".$fecha."'");
> ```

Y debería ser algo así:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT type, COUNT(name) FROM products GROUP BY type"; 
     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//imprimir resultado
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(name)'] ." ". $row['type'] ." items.";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Si no sabes que es **count** bueno sencillamente es una función de *MySQL* que te permite contar cuantos datos existen en un determinado rows osea filas.

[Fuente en ingles](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php) igual te recomiendo leer la docs de MySQL: [counting rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: **row** significa fila y **column** columna; corrige ese error

Comment: además la función de agregación por su propia naturaleza solo devuelve una fila, entonces es innecesario usar un iterador como `while` pues para que recorrer una sola fila?

Comment: ah si yase :p pero solo fue un  ejemplo que encontre :P mas creativo :) pero es innecario usar un while porque con una sola consulta internamente lo hace MYSQL, solo lo puse porque i me devuelve un error y lo siga intentando hasta que salga un true, aunque tambien podria usar un IF of un for pero es depende de la persona,.

Comment: @shadow oh "
row significa fila y column columna; corrige ese error – shadow hace 3 minutos
" oh si perdon se me fue el rollo pensando en columnas :p y